# Kähler manifold not deformable to singular projective variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I am trying to make sense of [this](https://totallydisconnected.wordpress.com/2019/05/01/p-adic-kahler-manifolds/) blog post.

Let $D$ be the unit disk endowed with its standard complex structure. A family of complex-analytic spaces over a disk is a proper holomorphic map $X\rightarrow D$ that is a submersion over $D\backslash\{0\}$.

Is there a closed complex manifold that satisfies Hodge symmetry and Hodge--de Rham degeneration and can not be put into a family of compact complex-analytic spaces over a disk with the central fiber being the analytification of a reduced scheme projective over $\mathbb{C}$?

Is there a closed Kähler manifold that can not be put into a family of compact complex-analyic spaces over a disk with the central fiber being the analytification of a reduced scheme projective over $\mathbb{C}$?

Note that if we require the the central fiber to be smooth, then there are examples due to Voisin. So singularities matter here.

Comment: Here is one approach.  Let $Y$ be a smooth, projective threefold with a large, finite, automorphism group with $h^{3,0}$ nonzero, e.g., a Fermat hypersurface in $\mathbb{CP}^4$ of degree $d\geq 5$.  Let $J$ denote the associated (non-projective) Griffiths intermediate Jacobian of that weight $3$ Hodge structure, with the induced action of the automorphism group of $Y$.  Let $X$ be the blowing up of $J\times J$ along the graphs of these finitely many automorphisms of $J$.  Are all deformations of $X$ induced from a deformation of $J\times J$ together with these graphs?